# Convert String to LocalDateTime Java 8

Tags: java, string, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

I'm trying to convert the following String into a LocalDateTime:

```
String dateStr = "2020-08-17T10:11:16.908732"; 

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, format);
```

But I'm hitting the following error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-08-17T10:11:16.908732' could not be parsed at index 10
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
```

Can anyone please help to advise how I should be correctly formatting the string into a LocalDateTime?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you seen that `T` separating the date from the time part in the `dateStr`? Your pattern does not consider it... And in addition, `n` means nanoseconds, but your example `String` contains just 6 *fractions of seconds* wich makes `S` appear more suitable here.

Comment: The format you're trying to parse is a standard format provided by Java by the way. You can use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` instead of using your own pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to specify a `DateTimeFormatter` in this case because the default one will be used if you don't pass one at all:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateStr = "2020-08-17T10:11:16.908732";
    // the following uses the DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME implicitly
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
}
```

That code will output `2020-08-17T10:11:16.908732`.

If you are insisting on using a custom `DateTimeFormatter`, consider the `T` by single-quoting it in the pattern and don't use nanosecond parsing (`n`) for parsing fractions of second (`S`), the result might be wrong otherwise.

Do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateStr = "2020-08-17T10:11:16.908732"; 
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, format);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
}
```

with the same output as above.

**Note:**
The result of using the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn"` would not be equal to the parsed `String`, instead, it would be

```
2020-08-17T10:11:16.000908732
```

Comment: Good answer! Keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

For your given DateTime string pattern should be updated `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn"`.

So the code should be like :

```
String dateStr = "2020-08-17T10:11:16.908732"; 

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, format);
```

For more details around it you can refer [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).

Along that in your given input DateTime it's using 6 digits, so it can't be nano seconds. Because nano is 1/1000000000. So it will have at least 9 digits. So the correct format rather should be second fraction with 6 digits as "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS".

***End Results comparison:***

**With Pattern : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn"**

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-17T10:11:16.908732", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn")));
```

> **Output** : 2020-08-7T10:11:16.000908732

**With Pattern : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"**

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-17T10:11:16.908732", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")));
```

> **Output** : 2020-08-7T10:11:16.908732

Comment: Have you printed the result of this parsing? It won't be equal to the `dateStr`!

Comment: thanks Gaurav. I did try and add the T to the formatter earlier, but didnt realise I needed to wrap it in single quotes e.g. 'T'

Comment: @deHaar : Yes correct it is using nanosecond which is 9 digits precision. It should rather use 6 digit precision.

Comment: Gaurav Jeswani - You don't need to use a `DateTimeFormatter` explicitly for the given date-time string. Check [this answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63449093/10819573) which not only mentions the idiomatic way of parsing this date-time string but also adding some other valuable information.